# Lighttpd and mod_access

Tags: lighttpd

I try to add mod_access to my server but everytime I run `lighttpd-enable-mod access`, it shows me the following output:

```
Available modules: auth accesslog cgi evasive evhost expire fastcgi flv-streaming no-www proxy rrdtool simple-vhost ssi ssl status userdir usertrack fastcgi-php debian-doc 
Already enabled modules: auth cgi fastcgi 
Run /etc/init.d/lighttpd force-reload to enable changes
```

so why is mod_access not available?
i though it comes by standard with lighty?
and most importantly how can i add it?

Answer (score 0):

I think mod_access is enabled by default.

Have you checked your `lighttpd.conf` ? You should have manually:

```
server.modules  = (
    "mod_access",
```

When I list module, I have:

```
lucid@lucid:/home/lucid# lighttpd-enable-mod
Available modules: auth cgi fastcgi proxy rrdtool simple-vhost ssi ssl status userdir
Already enabled modules: fastcgi simple-vhost
```

As you can see, I don't have mod_access here and it is enabled in my conf.